# How do I transpose multiple arrays unless an array element is empty?

Tags: ruby, arrays, transpose

I have the following code:

```
[array1, array2, array3].transpose
```

I want to do something like this:

```
[array1, array2, array3].transpose unless array2[value] == ""
```

I want to transpose each array, but when the value for `array2` that is being transposed is blank I want to skip to the next set of values altogether, ensuring that none of the arrays get transposed.

How can I handle that within Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: Suppose you have `[["a","b"], ["", "c"], ["d", "e"]]`. On `tranpose`, do you want the result as `["b", "c", "e"]` ?

Comment: That is correct. `["b", "c", "e"]` is the end goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this :

```
arr1 = ["a", "b"]
arr2 = ["",  "c"]
arr3 = ["d", "e"]
```

Now, as per your requirement,; you want those tranposed arrays where `arr2` *blank* value is not present.

Use `#reject` to do that as:

```
[arr1, arr2, arr3].transpose.reject{ |x| x[1].empty? }
```

Here, `x[1]` corresponds to the second element in each transposed array; and it comes from `arr2`; so here, we rejected all those instances where `""` was present in `arr2`.

Hope it helps

Comment: `.reject` - That does it. Never cease to be amazed...Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you had large arrays, and memory were a concern, you could reduce the size of the array before transposing it.  That's straightfoward.  Here's one way (`i` being the row containing one or more instances of `bad_obj`):

```
def tr(arr, i, bad_obj)
  bad_cols = []
  arr[i].each_with_index {|e,i| bad_cols << i if e==bad_obj}
  arr.map {|row| row.reject.with_index {|e,i| bad_cols.include?(i)}}.transpose
end
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,'',6], [7,8,9]]  
tr(arr, 1, "") # => [[1,4,7], [3,6,9]]
```

- construct an array bad_cols that contains the indices of the columns to be skipped.
- remove the bad_cols columns from each row, then apply transpose.

Edit: replaced

```
bad_cols = arr[i].each_with_index.reduce([]) {|a,e| a << e.last if e.first==bad_obj; a}
```

with the first two lines of `def tr()`.  Simpler is better.

Comment: It's always helpful and eye-opening to see other methods like this. No doubt this will help in the future - Thanks!